# Is there any way better than this to do a factory?

Tags: javascript

I have created a factory like this to create an specific object depending of a `select` value:

```
let myFactory = { "CREATE_DOCTOR" : function(){return new Doctor();}
                  "CREATE_NURSE" : function(){return new Nurse();}          
                  "CREATE_PATIENT" : function(){return new Patient();}
                };
let aPerson=[];

mySelect.addEventListener("change", function(){
  aPerson.push(myFactory["CREATE_"+mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value]());
}
```

Of course, I have all the classes that I can create in the factory and mySelect gets the reference to the html select. But my question is... Is there an (even) better way to do this? Because the other way that I know is doing a really big if/else that consider all alternatives, which makes the code less maintainable.

Comment: You will need to define what "better" means since it has wide meaning. On a quick looks I can say I do not like CAPS members for the myFactory API...why not `createDoctor` instead of `CREATE_DOCTOR`

Comment: Just different variations of the same. E.g. `let myFactory = {Doctor, Nurse, Patient};` and later just `new myFactory[mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value]()`.

Comment: @bhantol Ok. With "better" I mean a code which is easier to maintain than mine, or more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for those wrapper functions, and `select` elements have a `value` property, so:

```
var classes = {
    DOCTOR:  Doctor,
    NURSE:   Nurse,
    PATIENT: Patient
};
mySelect.addEventListener("change", function(){
    aPerson.push(new classes[mySelect.value]());
});
```

Example:

```js
function Doctor() {
  console.log("Creating a Doctor");
}
function Nurse() {
  console.log("Creating a Nurse");
}
function Patient() {
  console.log("Creating a Patient");
}
var classes = {
    DOCTOR:  Doctor,
    NURSE:   Nurse,
    PATIENT: Patient
};
var aPerson = [];
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
mySelect.addEventListener("change", function(){
    aPerson.push(new classes[mySelect.value]());
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="DOCTOR">Doctor</option>
  <option value="NURSE">Nurse</option>
  <option value="PATIENT">Patient</option>
</select>
```

For that matter, there's really no need for the names in all caps. On ES2015+ compatible JavaScript engines, it could just be:

```
const classes = {
    Doctor,
    Nurse,
    Patient
};
mySelect.addEventListener("change", function(){
    aPerson.push(new classes[mySelect.value]());
});
```

...where the values in the select were `"Doctor"`, `"Nurse"`, and `"Patient"`:

Example:

```js
class Doctor {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Creating a Doctor");
  }
}
class Nurse {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Creating a Nurse");
  }
}
class Patient {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Creating a Patient");
  }
}
const classes = {
    Doctor,
    Nurse,
    Patient
};
const aPerson = [];
const mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
mySelect.addEventListener("change", function(){
    aPerson.push(new classes[mySelect.value]());
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Doctor</option>
  <option>Nurse</option>
  <option>Patient</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, I won't ever figured out that I could do it like this last way. ES6 still surprising me :). Thanks!